# Django Listing in Page Issue, "Data Not Appearing"

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I ran into the problem that no results were listed when pulling a processed data into my SQlite class database. However, I did not encounter an error code.

Related pages will be a page where each member will see their profile page and information. I want the data to be pulled according to the column I defined named user_id other than id.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from .leagues_models import leagues
from .models import teams
from .news_models import news
from .players_models import players

def bilgilerim(request,id):
        bilgilerim_cek=players.objects.get(user_id=id)
        context={
            'bilgiler': bilgilerim_cek,
            'bilgitum': players.objects.filter(user_id=id),
        }
        return render(request,'profil/bilgilerim.html', context)
```

bilgilerim.html

```
{% for bilgilerim_x in players %}
            {{ bilgilerim_x }}
        <div class="TopInfoStatistic w-100">
            <p class="text-start w-75 float-start "><img class="m-0 p-0" src="../img/teams/{{ bilgilerim_x.team_id }}.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 15px; height: 15px;"><strong class="text-dark">Dumlupınar S.K</strong></p>
            <p class="text-end w-25 float-end align-middle">{{ bilgilerim_x.dogecoin }}<img class="align-content-center" src="../img/icon/dogecoin.svg" style="width: 14px; height: 14px;"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row w-100 InfoStatisticScore m-0 mb-3">
            <div class="w-25 float-start m-0 p-0 pe-3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#profilphoto">
                <img class="m-0 p-0 border rounded-3 border-warning" src="{{bilgilerim_x.photo}}" alt="Generic placeholder image" style="width: 90px; height: 90px;">
            </div>
            <div class="w-75 m-0 p-0">
                <p class="w-100 m-0 p-0 ps-3" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: 500;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#namesurname">{{bilgilerim_x.name_surname }}</p>
                <p class="w-100 m-0 p-0 ps-3" style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 500;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#mobilenumber">
                    {{ bilgilerim_x.mobile_number}}</p>
                <p class="w-100 m-0 p-0 ps-3" style="font-size: 14px;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ageheightweight">Yaş:
                    {{ bilgilerim_x.age }} - Boy: {{ bilgilerim_x.length }} - Kilo: {{ bilgilerim_x.weight }}</p>
                <p class="w-100 m-0 p-0 ps-3" style="font-size: 14px;" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#footposition">Ayak:
                    {{ bilgilerim_x.foot }} - Mevki: {{ bilgilerim_x.position }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        {%endfor%}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name='yonetim'),
    path('', views.anasayfa, name='home'),
    path('ligler/<int:id>', views.leagueLists, name='leagues'),
    path('haberler/',views.haberler, name='habers'),
    path('kayit/',views.kayit, name='kayit_x'),
    path('giris/',views.giris, name='giris_x'),
    path('cikis/',views.cikis, name='cikis_x'),
    path('bilgilerim/<int:id>',views.bilgilerim, name='bilgilerim_x'),
]
```

players_models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class players(models.Model):
    name_surname=models.CharField(max_length=18,null=False,blank=False)
    mobile_number=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    player_status=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    team_id=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    photo=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='resim-yok.jpg')
    awards=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    dogecoin=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    age=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    foot=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    length=models.CharField(max_length=4,null=False,blank=False)
    weight=models.IntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    red_card=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    position=models.CharField(max_length=2,null=False,blank=False)
    form_points=models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True,blank=True)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use

```
{% for bilgilerim_x in players %}
```

in your html but there is no "players" defined in context in your view:

```
context={
            'bilgiler': bilgilerim_cek,
            'bilgitum': players.objects.filter(user_id=id),
        }
```

Comment: Already have it. I just didn't post it here.

Are you saying this?

`from .players_models import players`

Comment: See uodated answer. You need to add players to the context={...}

Comment: `'players': players.objects.filter(user_id=id),` i did, fixed problem. Thank you!